# How can I use the WAN interface IP address(es) in NFTables config?

Tags: networking, firewall, ipv6, ipv4, nftables

**Background**
I'm attempting to write an NFTables configuration that would allow me to keep IPv4 and IPv6 forwarding rules in the same table.

I'm hosting some web services behind a reverse proxy and want to allow inbound traffic over ports 80 and 443 to that server.

With IPv4 only, I could create a rule `iifname { $WANLINK } tcp dport { 80, 443 } accept`, combined with a `dnat` rule `iifname { $WANLINK } tcp dport { 80, 443 } dnat to { $REVERSEPROXY }`, and the only thing reachable from outside would be the reverse proxy over the defined TCP ports.

**Issues**

- If I defined `inet` rules as described above while allowing IPv6 traffic I would allow *anybody* on the Internet access to TCP ports 80 and 443 on *any* server in my network.
- The only way I can think of to combine IPv4 and IPv6 forwarding rules in a single `inet` table would be to `accept` traffic based on the `daddr` property for both protocols. But as I have a residential Internet connection my public IPv4 address is based on DHCP and does - albeit rarely - change. This means I can't hard-code my current WAN IP address into my config and expect things to keep working indefinitely.

**Question**
Is there any way to tell NFTables to always use my current WAN IP address on the form `iifname { $WANLINK } ip daddr { <ip of $WANLINK> } tcp dport { 80, 443 } accept`?

Or am I missing another obvious solution to my question?

Comment: `fib daddr . iif type local` maybe

Comment: You should complete your description with additional information: do you intend to NAT IPv6 too, or will you just use a known and not changing IPv6 address for the reverse proxy (then why would you need to know the router/firewall's own address?) etc. Also you present rules in the wrong order. Instead of presenting snippets, you should present your actual IPv4 ruleset and tell where you're stuck to implement the IPv6 part. Actually I don't see where there's a problem to solve (and thus not even the need to use `fib` for this case).

Comment: i have a use case for this, and it's a NAT router on a dynamic IP address configuration, where i want to setup reflection rules. normally, i'd do `daddr $WANIP/32 dport 80 dnat to 10.0.0.1:80` but i don't want to hardcode `$WANIP` there.